# Php string get letter of index

Tags: php

I want to get the letter of a certain 'index' within a string. I know there is the strpos function but this is pretty much the opposite I want to do.

For instance:

```
$String = 'Hello';
echo getIndexOf(4, $String);
```

It would return 'o';

Is there any way I can do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: so, which letter do you want returned?

Comment: btw; get in the habit of accepting answers for solutions given. This for answers possibly posted below and for your previous questions that provided you with solutions, being a "win-win" thing ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-   .. this user  .. have not accepted  an answer  never .. .. we hope that he  understand that it is not fair to behave so

Comment: @scaisEdge I take it that *"we hope that you understand that it is not fair to behave so"* was aimed at the OP ;-) and not *moi*.

Comment: @Fred-ii-   yes .. i have edited  the comment ... google translate  in wrong way  but  .. i have soon updated .. (not  so  soon seems)

Comment: @scaisEdge that user doesn't seem to be able to lace its boots so, I wouldn't get my hopes too high.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier   ...  This is good .. you're probably right

Comment: I didn´t know it sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply do

```
$String[4]
```

or use the substr function :

```
substr($String, 4, 1).
```